# UIScrollView not recognizing button click event when scrolled to bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

My view hierarchy is
UIScrollView -> ContainerView -> [ subviews .. n ]

Here when the scrollview loads for the first time the views which are in visible area are clickable, but when i scroll and the bottom views come to visible area they do not respond to click.
I am new to ios and dealing with uiscrollview really tough.

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    var contentRect : CGRect = CGRectZero;
    for view in self.container.subviews {
        contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame)

    }
    self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;

}
```

Here is a code i am using for the scrollview to decide its contents height.

Comment: What approach are you using, storyboards or something else? Can you verify that `container` size is big enough?

Comment: i am using storyboard. and container size is big coz i can scroll the scrollview till the end.

Comment: @said sikira can u send me a sample working code of uiscrollview, where contentsize is grater that frame size

Comment: so you want scrolling more than 568 size of storyboard?